# Test remote server cert against locally stored cert before trusting

Tags: powershell

I have some code that I use to connect to a web server that we own.  The server has a self signed certificate.  I am currently connecting with the trust any cert

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback {$true}.
```

How can I change this so that I can either test the remote server with custom code or against a cert in my local store?  For example can I change the code above to

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$customValidator}
```

What I would like to do is, instead of trusting any/all certs, I would like to trust it only if it matches with the public key cer file I have or I would like to test the certificate using custom code.  The thing I am not very clear on is how to handle the custom verification and at what point in the code. Do I need to write an entire class to handle custom SSL validation or is there a better way to do this?

```
$url = "https://myWebServer"
$web = New-Object Net.WebClient
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true } 
//[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { customSslCertValidation } #I would like to do something like this    
$output = $web.DownloadString($url) 
Write-Host $output
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {
  $c = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]$args[1]
  ($c.Thumbprint -eq "StoredOrRetrievedHash")
}
```

This checks the Thumbprint of the certificate returned as part of the request against the string "StoredOrRetrievedHash". You would want to replace that with the details from your certificate loaded in dynamically. It is worth noting that the first line of the scriptblock delegate casts the second element of the $args array to be an object of type [X509Certificate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx), as the bare [X509Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.aspx) object doesn't expose the Thumbprint property.

*Note: this only works in PowerShell v2 and later - in v1 assigning an arbitrary scriptblock to a delegate was a lot of extra work and quite frankly, just not worth the effort typically.*